# DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode enum value not valid

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridviewrow

I have this error no matter what I do; I get an InvalidEnumArgumentException thrown when using the DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode enum. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 currently, but the error also seems to be present in 2017.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create a new blank vb.net winforms project
2. add the code below into the load event
3. run the project

   ```
   Public Class Form1
       Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
           Dim DataGrid As New DataGridView
           DataGrid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode.AllCells
           Me.Controls.Add(DataGrid)
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```

Here is a screenshot of the exception in Visual Studio:

[Visual studio 2015 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCoM0.png)

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?!?

Comment: [DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizerowmode(v=vs.110).aspx) is not the same as [DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizerowsmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me insane!